# How to remove the share and print option from implicit intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Below is my code to open implicit intent for to show list of image supported apps:

```
 private fun getProfileImage() {
        file = ViewUtility.getCaptureImageOutputFilePath(
            mActivity,
            mActivity.getString(R.string.str_profile_file_name)
        )
        val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            mActivity,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + mActivity.getString(R.string.file_provider_name),
            file
        )
      
        val intent = ViewUtility.getPickImageIntent(mActivity, imageUri)
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeGetProfileImage)
    }
    
    fun getCaptureImageOutputFilePath(context: Context, fileName: String): File {

        val folder = File("${context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)}")
        folder.mkdirs()
        val file = File(folder, fileName)
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete()
        file.createNewFile()
      
        return file
    }

    
     fun getPickImageIntent(context: Context, cameraOutputUri: Uri): Intent? {
        var chooserIntent: Intent? = null
        var intentList: MutableList<Intent> = ArrayList()
        val pickIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        val takePhotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraOutputUri)

        intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent)
        intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent)

        if (intentList.size > 0) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                intentList.removeAt(intentList.size - 1),
                null
            )
            chooserIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                intentList.toTypedArray<Parcelable>()
            )
        }

        return chooserIntent
    }
```

I want to show  only the related applications option This is faced only in Android 10 OS version

Android , kotlin , Android 10 version

[image]